# C# ValueMemberやDisplayMemberを設定したListBoxから項目を削除する方法

Tags: c#, winforms

お世話になります。

C#のListBoxで、ValueMemberとDisplayMemnerを設定した後、
自由に項目を削除したいと考えています。

下記の様なソースで、初めにDataTableで管理できるようにし、addItemメソッドで
項目を追加するところまで作成しました。

```
public void init()
{
    this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("ＭＳゴシック", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(128)));
    this.ScrollAlwaysVisible = true;

    this.Items.Clear();

    //DataTableオブジェクトを用意
    dtItem = new DataTable();

    //DataTableに列を追加
    dtItem.Columns.Add("VALUE", typeof(string));
    dtItem.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));

    //リストボックスのDataSourceにDataTableを割り当てる
    this.DataSource = dtItem;

    //表示される値はDataTableのNAME列
    this.DisplayMember = "NAME";

    //対応する値はDataTableのValue列
    this.ValueMember = "VALUE";

}

public void addItem(string id,string name)
{
    //新しい行を作成
    DataRow row = dtItem.NewRow();

    //各列に値をセット
    row["VALUE"] = id;
    row["NAME"] = name;
    dtItem.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

ここから、removeItem(string id)などのようなメソッドで、
項目が削除できると良いのですが、DataTable.Rows.Removeメソッドなどでは
DataRowを渡さなければならなかったり、どのように削除を行えばよいのか、
途方に暮れています。

解決方法をお教えいただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一番基礎的な方法はループによるものです。削除時にインデックスが変わるため逆順ループにしています。

```
for (var i = dtItem.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var row = dtItem.Rows[i];
    if (id.Equals(row["VALUE"]))
    {
        dtItem.Rows.Remove(row);
        // 一件削除ならbreak;する
    }
}
```

LINQを使う場合は以下の通りです。

```
var row = dtItem.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Field<string>("VALUE") == id);
if (row != null)
{
    dtItem.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

複数行削除であれば`ToArray()`などで削除対象を一時的なリストに格納します。

```
var rows = dtItem.AsEnumerable().Where(_ => _.Field<string>("VALUE") == id).ToArray();
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    dtItem.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

レガシーな手法ですが、`DataRow`の抽出には`Select`という手もあります。

```
var rows = dtItem.Select("VALUE='" + id + "'");

//以下略
```

またテーブルに主キーを設定しておけば`Find`で検索できます。

```
// 一度だけ実行する
dtItem.PrimaryKey = new[] { dtItem.Columns["VALUE"] };

var row = dtItem.Rows.Find(id);

//以下略
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。Linqを使用する方法で、難なく実現できました。
できるようにはなったものの、どうもこのLINQというものがまだよく理解できていません。
これを機に、もっと勉強してみたいと思います。
また何かありましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

ソースがDataTableと予め判っているなら、DataViewを作ってFindRowsするのが楽です。
そうでなくソースが不定な状態であるなら以下のように、ListBox.DataManagerからCurrentcyManagerを取って、そこからDataViewを取り出すことができます。

DataViewが取れれば後はValueMemberをキーにして検索するとDataRowViewが得られるので、そのDataRowView.Rowが対象のDataRowになります。

```
public void RemoveItemByID(string id) //このコードはListBoxを継承したクラス内のいうメソッド
{
    var manager = this.DataManager as CurrencyManager;
    if (manager == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (manager.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    var dv = manager.List as System.Data.DataView;
    if (dv != null && false)
    {
        var dt = dv.Table;
        var column = dt.Columns[this.ValueMember];
        if (dt.PrimaryKey != null && dt.PrimaryKey.Length == 1 && dt.PrimaryKey[0] == column)
        {
            //プライマリーキーならそのままをキーにして削除
            int index = dv.Find(id);
            dv.Delete(index);
        }
        else
        {
            //見つかったのを入れておくリスト
            List<DataRow> foundRows = new List<DataRow>();//プライマリーキーでない場合は複数見つかる可能性がある

            if (false)
            {
                //プライマリーキーでない場合は一時的にDataViewを作って
                //そのDataViewで検索を行う
                var dvTemp = new System.Data.DataView(dv.Table);
                dvTemp.Sort = this.ValueMember;//検索する列名を指定


                foreach (DataRowView drv in dvTemp.FindRows(id))
                {
                    foundRows.Add(drv.Row);
                }
                //見つかったのを削除
                foreach (DataRow row in foundRows)
                {
                    dv.Table.Rows.Remove(row);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //DataViewを作るまでもないなら自分で探す
                foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
                {
                    object value = drv[this.ValueMember];
                    if ((value == null && id == null)
                    || (value != null && id == value.ToString()))
                    {
                        foundRows.Add(drv.Row);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in foundRows)
            {
                dv.Table.Rows.Remove(row);
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //DataViewでないならIBindingListか調べる
        var bindingList = manager.List as System.ComponentModel.IBindingList;
        if (bindingList != null)
        {
            var props = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(bindingList[0]);
            foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor pd in props)
            {
                if (pd.Name == this.ValueMember)
                {
                    var index = bindingList.Find(pd, id);
                    if (index >= 0)
                    {
                        bindingList.RemoveAt(index);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {   //IBindingListですらないなら全部をリフレクションで
            for (int index = this.Items.Count - 1; index >= 0; --index)
            {
                object o = this.Items[index];
                if (o != null)
                {
                    var pi = o.GetType().GetProperty(this.ValueMember);
                    if (pi != null)
                    {
                        object value = pi.GetValue(o, null);
                        if ((value == null && id == null)
                        || (value != null && id == value.ToString()))
                        {
                            this.Items.Remove(index);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。
回答例ですが、とても長いソースですが、やはりこれだけ厳重に処理しないと
成功しないものなのでしょうか。Javaなんかと比べると、もっと簡単にできたような
気がするだけに、少し戸惑ってしまいます。
これを機に、もう少し勉強してみたいと思います。

Comment: 最初に書いたようにDataSourceが"DataTableとわかっているなら"ば他の方の回答のように簡単なループで調べらます。
ですが、わかっていない場合には他の可能性に対応できるように以上のコードとなっています。